Pynput mouse.move() function does not stop when it reaches edge of screen
When I'm using the mouse.move() function with the Pynput package, the mouse does not stop moving when it reaches the edge of the screen. For example with the following code:
from pynput.mouse import Controller

mouse = Controller()

 while 1:
     mouse.move(0,-10)
     print(mouse.position)
     time.sleep(2)

The mouse position printed will keep going more and more negative even when it hits the edge of the screen. I can manually constrain the cursor position based on the screen size but is there a built in function that will do this with Pynput or any other Python package?
I do not want the cursor to move off the screen even when the mouse.move() function says to.

I can't reproduce the behavior you speak about. Linux Mint 21 Xfce Python 3.10 pynput 1.7.6 .

Same here on Win11 pynput 1.7.6

Seems like it is only an issue on Mac, I tested it on Linux and it does not go beyond the edges on the screen. Is there a way to do this on Mac as well?
